# Gson does not parse json String

Tags: android, json, migration, gson, androidx

Now I'm working on an Android SDK project, the code is too old and I tried to collect data from server using [okhttp3](https://square.github.io/okhttp/). By using the following function I'm able to collect the response from server.

```
String json = requestGetString(url);

    public String requestGetString(String uri) throws IOException {
    Response res = null;
    try {
        res = getStringHttp(host+uri);
        System.out.println(res.body().string());
        return res.body().string();
    }catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //body = null ??
        throw new IOException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }finally {
        if(res != null){
            try{
                res.close();
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                //body = null ??
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm receiving the Json but I'cant parse it with my data class.

like the following

```
 AuthAppResponse result = parseJson(path, json, AuthAppResponse.class);
```

You can look my parser function

```
private <TResponse> TResponse parseJson(String path, String json, Class<TResponse> responseClass) throws IOException
{
    return parseJson(getGson(), path, json, responseClass);
}
```

and this,

```
private <TResponse> TResponse parseJson(Gson gson, String path, String json, Class<TResponse> responseClass) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        return gson.fromJson(json, responseClass);
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException e)
    {
        throw new IOException("The response from '" + path + "' failed to be parsed as JSON.\ncontent = " + json, e);
    }
}
```

Nothing happen.

And the same SDK with latest code base it works fine with the same code. Anyone have an idea to figure out the possible solution for this.
please share your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fount the missing part in my code, I miss to add a [proguard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) file in the old project, that's why the Gson does not parse the response

Answer (score 1):

[You can consume an okhttp response body only once](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/#the-response-body-can-be-consumed-only-once). You're consuming it twice. First in:

```
System.out.println(res.body().string());
```

and then in

```
return res.body().string();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just removed the one in my code, and tried it  again, but the issue still courses